# Increment/Decrement values by .01 in Google Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to increment/decrement values by .01 in Google Chrome Devtools using the up and down arrows? This is done often enough that I'm shocked you have to hit the backspace and type the number manually. I should be able to hit the up and down arrow while holding another key to increment/decrement by hundredths. This would help for modifying the alpha channel on any rgba color on the fly.

Example:

[image]

Comment: @MarcB "mythical"? This is default behavior in other dev tools because it is the expected behavior of the developer. In other dev tools you don't even need a modifier key, just up/down arrows when adjusting decimal values.

Answer (score 7):

Highlight the value and press:

- Up/Down = +/-1
- Alt + Up/Down = +/-0.1
- Shift + Up/Down (or PgUp/PgDn) = +/-10
- Shift + PgUp/PgDn = +/-100

Sadly, no 0.01 incrementor though.

Just hit F1 and look at the shortcuts menu.